# Populate Maxmind Database with your own Datasets coming from different source

Tags: mysql, sql, geolocation, geoip, maxmind

I am currently using `Maxmind Geolite` database. I have one table named `GEO_IP_CITY_BLOCKS_0` in which columns are there as-

```
START_IP_NUM     END_IP_NUM     LOCATION_ID
```

Sample data in the above table-

```
7602176           7864319           16
16777216          16777471          17
```

I know, If I am looking for IP Address, then I need to convert that IP Address to long so that means I can use the below query in MySql to get the `LOCATION_ID` and then basis on `LOCATION_ID` I can do further lookup to get `City`, `State` etc etc.-

```
SELECT * FROM `GEO_IP_CITY_BLOCKS_0` WHERE INET_ATON("174.36.207.186") BETWEEN start_ip_num AND end_ip_num
```

Now my questions are-

1. Suppose for any `IP Address`, if there is `no range`, then I won't be able to get any LOCATION_ID right? And then I cannot do further lookup as LOCATION_ID is not there?.
2. And how these `START_IP_NUM` and `END_IP_NUM` gets decided meaning on what factors in `Maxmind database`?

Why I am asking this is, suppose if for any `IP Address` there is no range in MySql Maxmind database, then what I was thinking is to make my own range and put data corresponding to that IP Address from other sources in my MySql database (Maxmind).

Has anyone tried populating there own `datasets` in `Maxmind database` if for some reason data is not there for that particular IP Address in Maxmind?

Please let me know your thoughts.

**For example-**

Just like for this IP Address `105.160.159.59`, I don't have any range in my `Maxmind database` as I tried by executing this SQL

`SELECT * FROM GEO_IP_CITY_BLOCKS_0 WHERE INET_ATON("105.160.159.59") BETWEEN start_ip_num AND end_ip_num`

But for the same IP Address, I can get the data from other sources, So what I am looking for is- Is there any way I can populate the datasets in Maxmind database for similar use cases that I described above?

Comment: Most geo-location databases have data for almost all IP ranges -- they collapse contiguous IP ranges to save space.  Maybe I don't understand the question -- you want to add new ranges, or break up existing ones?

Comment: I was in the impression that for some `IP Address`, it might be possible that the ranges are not there in the database. Just like for this IP Address `105.160.159.59`, I don't have any range in my Maxmind database as I tried by executing this SQL `SELECT * FROM GEO_IP_CITY_BLOCKS_0 WHERE INET_ATON("105.160.159.59") BETWEEN start_ip_num AND end_ip_num`. But for this IP Address, I can get the data from other sources, So what I was asking is- Is there any way I can populate the datasets in Maxmind database for similar use cases?

Comment: I suppose the 'lite' version might not be complete -- but there's nothing stopping you from adding such a record.  If it's just a single IP, then start_ip_num == end_ip_num.

Comment: It's not a lite version first of all that I am using. But how about if  there are bunch of IP Addresses then what I should be doing in that case? And what start_ip_num and end_ip_num I am suppose to choose?

Comment: The original post indicates `MaxMind GeoLite` (i.e. free).  Anyway, you just need to store the unsigned integer equivalent of your IP address (using `INET_ATON`).  If they are non-contiguous ranges, you'll need multiple such entries, with start == end.